# finding td count in a row of a table in iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

When I click in a table cell of a table in an iframe, I want to be able to find out how many cells are in a row, if a cell is a span I would like to be able to use the span as the cell count.

The frame can contain many tables without classes but I can't get the count, it is way higher than it should be

```
iframe.find('td').click(function () {
            var thisCell = $(this);
            var thisRow = thisCell.closest('tr');
            var thisTbody = thisRow.closest('tbody');
            var thisTable = thisRow.closest('table');

            var url = "@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("_TableAttr")))";

            var d1 = $.Deferred();

            $.when(d1).then(function () {
                var tds = $(thisTable).children('tbody').children('tr').children('td').length;
                alert(tds);
            });

            d1.resolve(LoadNewsSideBarContent(url));
```

I have tried a .each function looping through the table > tbody> row > td but still strange counts.  I feel like the way I am storing the table in the variables is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, you can find all elements of a type in an element like thi :

```
 var listOfElements = $("#parentElementName").find("cell");
```

This will return all cells of your parent element.
And than using JavaScript, you can find the count of cells like :

```
   var count = listOfElements.length;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,

var listOfElements = $(thisRow).find("cell");
                var count = listOfElements.length;
                alert(count);

Return 0

Comment: I'am not sure that var thisRow = thisCell.closest('tr'); returns the clicked row. Did you try to give IDs to your rows ? Such, you can check if you search in the clicked row.

Comment: I added some code to change the back ground color and it all lined up